# Special Characters that can't be indexed using lucene

Tags: apache, indexing, lucene

I know the list of special characters that can be indexed using Apache Lucene. Can some one tell me if there are any special characters that cannot be indexed using Apache Lucene library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \

So basically it looks like you can index anything, just have to escape it.