# List of forbidden character in Lucene query for Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, riak

I got a setup of a Solr search engine on a Riak database.
When I am trying to realize a search with the following query:

```
my_field:#
```

I a paring query error from **Solr**

I also tried to query as follow

```
my_field:"#"
```

**Edit**:

I finnaly found a solution for the `#` character. (By encoding it with the URI code `%23`).

#### Is there a complete list of forbidden character in Lucene query for Solr?

Comment: What kind of field is `my_field` in your Solr core? The "#" should be honored if the field is of type `string` but it would be ignored in a `text_general` field.

Comment: @HectorCorrea in my schema it is of type string as defined by the yz default schema

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special Characters that can't be indexed using lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455237/special-characters-that-cant-be-indexed-using-lucene)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is not that "#" is a forbidden character in Solr queries, but the way you are running the query — using a browser, probably from the built-in Solr console in Riak.

This character requires encoding when sent **in a URL** (see [Percent-encoding in a URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters), [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2)). In which case you solution is the right one. The full list is:

```
! # $ & ' ( ) * + , / : ; = ? @ [ ]
```

However, it is not forbidden in Solr queries according to [Escaping Special Characters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/the-standard-query-parser.html#escaping-special-characters) of the latest Solr Ref Guide:

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : /
```

You should not have this problem when sending the query programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with `#` is that it has special meanings *in urls*. So your browser never sends it to the Solr server at all. The `#` denotes a local anchor, and anything after it is never sent to the server.

So if you have a HTTP query string such as `?q=field:#<whatever>`, the only thing Solr will receive from your browser is `?q=field:`. This is not a valid query.

This is independent of which characters have to be escaped *inside Solr's (or Lucene's) query syntax*.